# Regex to match uppercase Expressions and Words

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

Using Sublime Text 3 I want to extract only uppercase words and expressions from a text.

Example:
Hello world! It's a SUNNY DAY for all.

If I use the find tool, I can extract all uppercase words separately by using this regex:

```
\b[A-Z]+\b
```

The results are SUNNY and DAY, but I would like to consider SUNNY DAY as a whole to extract trough the find tool, without leaving behind simple words like in:

```
It's SUNNY today.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use

```
\b[A-Z]+(?:\s+[A-Z]+)*\b
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kZ6eO8/1)

I added `(?:\s+[A-Z]+)*` to the regex to match 0 or more sequences of:

- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespace
- `[A-Z]+` - 1 or more characters from `A-Z` range.

[image]

Note that in case you need to match Unicode uppercase letters, use `\p{Lu}` instead of `[A-Z]` (it will also match accented letters):

```
\b\p{Lu}+(?:\s+\p{Lu}+)*\b
```

Comment: Regexper [illustation](http://regexper.com/#\b[A-Z]%2B%28%3F%3A\s%2B[A-Z]%2B%29*\b)