# Regular expression Regex - Concatenate only uppercase words in R

Tags: r, regex

I have this content:

"Solar_pv SOLARES DE LA PUNTA 5.54 12/27/19"
 "Biogas BIO JUSTO DARACT 1.07 1/14/20"

I would like to create a regex that will concatenate all the uppercase words with an underscore, for instance:

**SOLARES_DE_LA_PUNTA** and **BIO_JUSTO_DARACT**

How can I do it in R and regex?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

assuming that none of the non capitalized words end with a capital letter you can just substitute any space surrounded by capital letters for an underscore:

```
strngs <- c("Solar_pv SOLARES DE LA PUNTA 5.54 12/27/19", "Biogas BIO JUSTO DARACT 1.07 1/14/20")
gsub("([A-Z]) ([A-Z])", "\\1_\\2", strngs)
[1] "Solar_pv SOLARES_DE_LA_PUNTA 5.54 12/27/19"
[2] "Biogas BIO_JUSTO_DARACT 1.07 1/14/20"      
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```r
vec <- c("Solar_pv SOLARES DE LA PUNTA 5.54 12/27/19", "Biogas BIO JUSTO DARACT 1.07 1/14/20")
gre <- gregexpr("[A-Z][A-Z ]+[A-Z]", vec)
regmatches(vec, gre)
# [[1]]
# [1] "SOLARES DE LA PUNTA"
# [[2]]
# [1] "BIO JUSTO DARACT"
regmatches(vec, gre) <- lapply(regmatches(vec, gre), function(s) gsub(" ", "_", s))
vec
# [1] "Solar_pv SOLARES_DE_LA_PUNTA 5.54 12/27/19"
# [2] "Biogas BIO_JUSTO_DARACT 1.07 1/14/20"
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to return only the upper case words back? If that is so using the regex from [Wiktor's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34066184/3962914) we can do

```
gsub(' ', '_', stringr::str_extract(x, '\\b[A-Z]+(?:\\s+[A-Z]+)*\\b'))
#[1] "SOLARES_DE_LA_PUNTA" "BIO_JUSTO_DARACT"
```

But as other answers have pointed out if you want to change only part of the text we can use `str_replace`  with the same regex

```
stringr::str_replace(x, "\\b[A-Z]+(?:\\s+[A-Z]+)*\\b", 
         function(m) gsub(" ", "_", m))

#[1] "Solar_pv SOLARES_DE_LA_PUNTA 5.54 12/27/19" 
#[2] "Biogas BIO_JUSTO_DARACT 1.07 1/14/20"
```

**data**

```
x <- c("Solar_pv SOLARES DE LA PUNTA 5.54 12/27/19", 
       "Biogas BIO JUSTO DARACT 1.07 1/14/20")
```